# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) with googletrans

Tags: python-3.x, google-translate

I want to be able to translate thanks to the google translate API, but it does not work

I use python3.6.2
and googletrans-2.4.0
What is extremely weird is that it worked 15 minutes ago. I changed nothing

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
translator.translate('안녕하세요.')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/googletrans/client.py", line 172, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/googletrans/client.py", line 81, in _translate
    data = utils.format_json(r.text)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/googletrans/utils.py", line 62, in format_json
    converted = legacy_format_json(original)
  File "lib/python3.6/site-packages/googletrans/utils.py", line 54, in legacy_format_json
    converted = json.loads(text)
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: What does it do in `lib/python3.6/site-packages/googletrans/utils.py` on line 54?

Answer (score 1):

Google has a limit on how much translation you can do after a particular amount of time, and that error message is just them telling you that you've reached that limit. You'll probably have to wait for some time before trying it again. By then the ban on your ip would have been lifted.